# Long user name clipping on question page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

In [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5839/saw-people-referring-as-i-am-married-with-three-kids), the long user name of the person asking the question is clipped by the box it is contained in (OS X Chrome and Safari).  I assume that this is not intentional and that the name should wrap down to the next line. If wrapping is not wanted, then probably at least ellipsis (...) would be good.

Comment: It also does it on Windows with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Names will clip if they are particularly long. I don't feel an ellipsis is necessary, because it would take up even more space i.e.

> My Name is Too L

vs.

> My Name is Too...